# Are there any fMRI decoding papers examining the relationship between attentional cueing and activity in V1?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, attention, fmri, cueing

I'm interested in reading on the influence of exogenous attention on cortical representations in early visual areas, but so far my google-fu seems to be failing me.

There seems to be some literature involving *endogenous* attention (Kamitani & Tong 2006, for instance), but nothing involving cueing, for instance.

**Does anybody know of any papers demonstrating either of the following?**

1. fMRI decoding of the effects of attentional cueing on V1?
2. fMRI decoding of (cued) attentional effects on V1 activity using at-threshold stimuli?

Thanks very much in advance!

**Edit:**  Okay, so I found two that hit the topic center-mass:

- Kok et al., 2011  *Less Is More: Expectation Sharpens
  Representations in the Primary Visual Cortex*
- Kok et al., 2012  *Attention Reverses the Effect of Prediction in Silencing Sensory Signals*

Anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha, I was going to mention the Kok Neuron paper :) The Cerebral Cortex one does not use decoding however.

This one may also be of interest to you:
Vetter, P., Smith, F. W., & Muckli, L. (2014). Decoding Sound and Imagery Content in Early Visual Cortex. Current Biology, 24(11), 1256-1262.

Lars Muckli is in general someone who might have more of the same.

I also know [this lab](http://jeheelab.org/publications.html) does decoding and attention and V1, so maybe some of those publications will capture all three.

I'll edit later if I think of something else.